# com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Access denied

Tags: java, windows, registry, jna

Right now, I'm trying to read the Windows Registry using the  com.sun.jna.platform.win32 library in Java. When the program is executed, it reads a lot of keys and values, but at some point, the program throws an exception that says: "com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: Access denied". Is there any way to skip this exception and continue reading the rest of keys and values of the registry?

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can catch that exception.

Comment: I tried to catch the exception,but it stills showing same error. I tried to catch in this way:

try{
}catch(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception we){
                we.toString();
            }

Probably I'm catching wrong...

Comment: Is anything in your `try` block?

Comment: Yes sir. In fact, I'm using the data
int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(base, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(cadena), new Integer(KEY_ALL_ACCESS) });

for managing access, but it didn't woked.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure then. Sorry!

Comment: I just fixed it!!! There were another block of code that was showing the same exception. So, I wrote another try-catch block right on this part of code. Thanks and sorry the dumb  question!!!